# Regex : Keep text between 2 keywords but only if another keyword exists inside them

Tags: regex, notepad++, emeditor

I am using emeditor and I am trying to isolate about 2 millions articles containing keyword3 from a french wikipedia dump .xml file (20GB, 338 millions rows, 4.8 millions articles in total).
I would like to keep the text contained between 2 keywords (keyword1 and keyword2) but only if another keyword (keyword3) exists inside them.

List of keywords :

```
keyword1 = <page>
keyword2 = </page>
keyword3 = {{Infobox
```

*Example A:*

```
keyword1 = <page>
text to consider without keyword3
keyword2 = </page>
```

Result => do not extract (or keep or split) this part.

*Example B:*

```
keyword1 = <page>
text to consider with keyword3
keyword2 = </page>
```

Result => extract (or keep or split) this part.

The author of Emeditor helped me with the following :

```
Find (choose regular expression):
<page>(.*?{{Infobox.*?)</page>
Replace with
\1
And in Advanced... : search in 2500 lines
```

It seems to work overall fine but from time to time some errors are appearing :
I am joining some tiny samples here : https://www.cjoint.com/c/JErsTJnVQpD
I also added a small desired results xml file.
As you can see in the joined image, the highlighted part in blue color (2 articles) should not have been included in the result part as they don't have the keyword *{{Infobox* .
Note: It also would be nice if the tag   is keep in the results.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Please don't attach files unless you have to. Can you put a couple examples of those incorrect matches right here?

Answer (score 2):

Left in the metaphor keywords, subtitute for needed
Since have gigabytes this is fastest way to do
Try:

`(?s)keyword1.*?(?:(?:keyword1|keyword2)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|keyword3).*?(?:keyword1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|keyword2)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8BhHpR/1)

Or with keyword substitons:

Find `(?s)<page>(.*?(?:(?:<page>|</page>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{{Infobox).*?)(?:<page>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|</page>)`
Replase `$1`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mf1nBE/1)

Not explain what quantifier is as some do - this is not about it
Expect to know basics

Comment: I've not seen use of the `/x` flag (*free-spacing mode*) in online regex testers before. Good idea. I'll borrow it in future.

Comment: Question seems to be about the extract feature of that commercial editor. I recommend using a simple Perl program to _Extract_ text and put into another file. You can control it more by adding annotations where it came from, etc ...

Comment: Hello, After some more tests, Edward's Method is 5 time faster than Yutaka's one. Alas it wrongly kept a lot (about twice more than needed) of `<page> content </pages>` without `{{Infobox)` inside them !

Comment: Good to know, enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **EmEditor**, in the **Replace** dialog box:

- Find:
  `<page>((?:(?!<page>).)*?{{Infobox.*?)</page>`
- Replace with:
  `<page>\1</page>`

Make sure **New Document** is selected in the menu displayed when you click ▼ by the **Extract** button.

[image: EmEditor Replace dialog box]

In the **Advanced** dialog:

- Set the **Regular Expressions “.” Can Match Newline Characters** check box.
- Enter `3000` (or the maximum number of lines you need to extract from one occurrence of regex) at the **Additional Lines to Search for Regular Expressions** text box

[image]

Finally, click the **Extract** button in the **Replace** dialog box.

Comment: Why big explain for _Extract_ feature ?  And doesnt it have that with find only. Why do you replace with exactly what you match ? Why not just  regex no capture, replace with `$&` using boost, yes?  And generaley if dissalow to get _inner_ tag, should check on the other side too `{{Infobox(?:(?!<page>).)*?`. And this regex will take 15 times longer than a `(*SKIP)(?!)` approach adding hours to 300GB searches. Finally, do you run boost regexs in a separate thread incase they become loop locked ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the *keyword1* from matching between *keyword1* and *keyword3*. Use

*Find What*: `(?s)<page>((?:(?!<page>).)*?{{Infobox.*?)</page>`
*Replace with*: `\1`

Here,

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier (same as if `.` matches newlines were ON)
- `<page>` - *keyword1* text
- `((?:(?!<page>).)*?{{Infobox.*?)` - Group 1: any char, 0 or more occurrences but as few as possible, not starting a `<page>` char sequence

  - `(?:(?!<page>).)*?`
  - `{{Infobox` - *keyword2*
  - `.*?` - any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `</page>` - *keyword2* text